# UIActivityViewController iOS12.2: strange activity type titles

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios12

I'm implementing sharing functionality in my app. I'm sharing some text.
I found that some activity types (such as Mail, Message) in sharing action sheet has strange names (see image below).
On iOS11 everything is OK.
Does anyone know how to fix that?

Code sample:

```
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: ["Hey, look at this URL: https://stackoverflow.com"],
        applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak self] _, _, _, _ in
   //some actions on completion
}
present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

The names of apps/actions in the share sheet are not under your control unless you were the one who created the action. I would expect these strange names to disappear in a release build / when it's on testflight so could be worth giving that a shot.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, I know that app name in this sheet is system responsibility, but on iOS 11 the app names are correct. I have no possibilities to check this via Testflight for now, I'll try later.